# Scrolling canvas

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

This is probably something **really** basic as a tcl/tk newbie, but I've spent all day on it and have no idea where I'm going wrong:

I'm teaching myself from a mix of code I've been given (which probably isn't very well written), and the main `tcl/tk` resource site, so probably not picking up the best practices!

I have a single frame containing a single canvas, with a scrollbar.

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish

frame .f -bg blue
canvas .f.c1 -bg red -scrollregion "-1000 -1000 -1000 1000" \ 
        -yscrollcommand ".f.scroll set"

pack .f -fill both
pack .f.c1 -fill both -side left

scrollbar .f.scroll -command ".f.c1 yview scroll 10 units"
pack .f.scroll -side right -fill y -side right
```

however, when I run this and try and scroll, I get the error:

```
wrong # args: should be ".f.c1 yview scroll number units|pages"
```

which is exactly what I do have... what else do I need to add in?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use

```
scrollbar .f.scroll -command ".f.c1 yview"
```

for further details see the [Scrollbar tutorial](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11211)

**Edit**: <sub>Adding some info from the comments</sub>

The scrollbar `-command` callback adds the extra parameters itself, so you must not provide them, otherwise you have too many arguments.

Comment: Hmm.. it does seem that the documentation (https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/scrollbar.htm#M28) is a bit misleading

Comment: @ChrisW Did you check the example at the bottom of that page? Scrolling works pretty much the same way with all Tk widgets…

Comment: Yeh - trying to get my head round it, don't totally follow it though yet.  Why do the docs say `prefix scroll number units|pages` when this isn't really required?

Comment: the `number` and the `unit|pages` are provided as extra arguments for the -command callback.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn ...so why do I get an error when I do include them?!

Comment: because `.f.c1 yview scroll 10 units scroll 1 page` is an error.

Comment: But I have `scrollbar .f.scroll -command ".f.c1 yview scroll 10 units` - so do have the correct number of arguments according to the docs

Comment: @ChrisW: this behavior is described in the section of the documentation related to the xscrollcommand and yscrollcommand options. See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M12